# What factors determine whether an assault will be vigorously looked into pursued and charged by the police or not?

Tags: england-and-wales, police, evidence, assault, prosecution

Meet Bob. He has filmed some thugs assaulting him by shoving, hitting, kicking at him and forcibly taking his phone away on the street until a passerby finally strongly urged him to give it back.

Bob reports this criminal assault to the police some months later while submitting his incontrovertible video evidence.

What factors would determine the degree of rigour with which the police look into a pursue this crime?

Comment: Was Bob injured? Did he lose any property or suffer any damage to it? Does Bob know the identity of the assailants? How old are the assailants? Why was there a delay in reporting the crime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What factors would determine the degree of rigour with which the
> police look into a pursue this crime?

Among the factors would be:

- The severity of the harm caused by the crime. Murders get investigated in circumstances when muggings causing no physical injury and no property loss do not. Someone who returns property taken is less of a priority than someone who breaks a victim's arm and steals their life savings. Also, lots of effort in investigating and prosecuting a crime might not be worth it if the likely sanction will be a modest fine and a period of supervision while remaining in the community.
- The likelihood that the crime can be proved. Cold cases are always harder to prove. Cases with insufficient evidence to be likely to prove a case aren't worth the trouble. Cases with less credible witnesses are a lower priority. Cases with hard to identify suspects don't go far.
- The situation of the prime suspect(s), if know. If the prime suspect is known to be in prison on another charge already, for example, the urgency of an investigation is less great.
- How promptly the crime was reported. Delay in reporting shows a manifest lack of urgency on the part of the reporting party that makes them ask why they should rush when the victim didn't. It makes the case harder to prove. It makes finding the suspect harder. It could implicate a statute of limitations in some cases.
- The extent to which the crime would address a larger pattern of conduct or larger criminal organization. A one-off crime not likely to recur is a lower priority since keeping the streets safe is a higher priority than complete justice in all incidents. But if there have been many similar incidents that were not prosecuted for lack of good evidence like video evidence, it might be more attractive to investigation and prosecute.
- The existence of larger investigations unknown to the complaining person that a prosecution of this crime might interrupt. If the suspect is also part of a major cartel investigation that could be disrupted if the suspect knew he was "made" they police might refrain from prosecuting or investigating the incident.
- How busy the police are at the time the complaint is made. The case might get more attention on a slow day than a busy one.

Comment: With respect to the fourth point: "How promptly the crime was reported. Delay in reporting shows a manifest lack of urgency on the part of the reporting party that makes them ask why they should rush when the victim didn't). It makes the case harder to prove. It makes finding the suspect harder. It could implicate a statute of limitations in some cases."

Comment: A) perhaps it could be said that they should rush because it's their job to take complaints seriously while the complainant as a private individual may have any of a multitude of reasons. Is this line of thought not reasonable and sound? Would it make a difference if the victim/complainant has intended to report the crime all along but had a disability which prevented them from doing so?

Comment: B) if there is supplied video evidence how would it be harder to prove?

Comment: C) what if the complainant is able to proffer the assailant's workplace address so that they may be virtually as effortlessly found as any?

Comment: D) suppose that there is no relevant statute of limitations applicable.

Comment: @JosephP. "Is this line of thought not reasonable and sound?" No. "Would it make a difference if the victim/complainant . . . had a disability which prevented them from doing so?" Maybe. "if there is supplied video evidence how would it be harder to prove? " Yes. Video isn't all you need so investigation is harder and finding the suspect and witnesses can be harder or impossible.

Comment: @JosephP I think we've had about six or seven questions from you circling around a videotaped attempted mugging not being prosecuted. The police aren't required to do so. Let it go.

Comment: I don't think I've asked any questions about mugging per se to be honest.

Comment: Please trust that there's a method to my madness that is deeper significance than petty vendetta.

Comment: More than meets the eye suffice to say.

Comment: @JosephP. This is not the place to get specific legal advice in a particular situation you are actually in. If you want that hire a lawyer. This is a forum for general educational information about the law. Asking the same question in many ways doesn't change the answer.

Comment: That said they aren't all inspired by the same issue, nor are they all practically motivated per se (although sure some of them are). Often it's just about getting deep into a topic once I'm looking into it and then simply seeking to flesh out and deepen my understanding of the different aspects of a given issue.

Comment: The questions - some of them  - are inspired by actual situations I am in, others are inspired by situations I have heard of. Others still are purely imaginary from the outset formulated in order to illustrate a particular conceptual question that I'm wondering how it works in the law or the internal police processes. I like being informed and educated about the society I live in.

Comment: With all due respect which is in fact quite high to yourself, I can see 3. One asked in the last 15m inspired as a follow up to this one. One this one. Another on 27/09 that was more about phone seizure which I have a more abstract interest in due to privacy gerkdom

Comment: Again no disrespect intended.

Answer (score 3):

There are two related questions:

1. What factors determine how police will exercise their investigative discretion?
2. How will charging decisions be made?

## Investigative Discretion

I cannot enumerate the multitude of factors that inform the police's investigative discretion, but [this guide from the College of Policing](https://www.college.police.uk/app/investigation/investigation-process) is a good resource. At the initial stage, factors include: scene management, risk management, record keeping, community impact. The priorities are to: preserve life, preserve scenes, secure evidence, identify victims, and identify suspects. The initial investigation is aimed at dealing with the immediate needs of victims and witnesses and gathering enough information to allow an *investigative evaluation*.

Whether the investigation goes further depends on the circumstances of the crime, the material gathered so far, and resource requirements.

Eventually, the police will coordinate with Crown Prosecution Service to identify further investigative needs of the prosecution, if a charge has been laid or is being considered.

More specific steps are discussed [here](https://www.college.police.uk/app/investigation/managing-investigations). Importantly:

> Each force sets their own crime investigation standards, which are disseminated to staff. They should be interdependent with the national intelligence model, to ensure that they support the deployment of appropriate resources to areas of identified priority at the correct time.
>
> Police officers exercise a high level of discretion when dealing with situations on the street. This is not directly overseen by sergeants and inspectors, and this makes the supervision of frontline officers challenging. Crime investigation standards are, therefore, useful to monitor and measure the performance of individual investigators and the quality of the investigation.

## Prosecutorial Discretion

Here are two resources describing the charging decision:

- College of Policing, [Charging and case preparation](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/charging-directors-guidance-sixth-edition-december-2020)
- Crown Prosecution Service, [Charging (The Director's Guidance)](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/charging-directors-guidance-sixth-edition-december-2020)

The default is that in order to charge, prosecutors must be satified that there is sufficient evidence to provide a realistic prospect of conviction *and* that there are no public interest factors tending against prosecution which outweigh factors in favour of prosecution.

But, there are a limited range of cases in which the seriousness or circumstances of a case justify making an immediate charging decision, even though there is insufficient evidence to meet the "realistic prospect of conviction" standard. In order to charge in these special circumstances, five conditions must be met. I will not describe these in detail, but there must reasonable grounds to suspect that the person has committed the offence (this is a lower standard than a "realistic prospect of conviction"), there must be further evidence forthcoming, the seriousness of the case justifies making an immediate decision, there are substantial grounds to object to bail, and it is in the public interest to charge.

Further, there is a lot of discretion for police or prosecutors to proceed with an out-of-court disposal where it is in the public interest and is an appropriate response.